# Grails: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum const

Tags: java, grails, groovy, grails-orm

I'm trying to work with an app that's been built in Grails, but I'm getting an error I don't understand.  Basically, I've got an enum:

```
package com.wbr.manning.common
public enum ChapterType {
  CHAPTER("chapter"), PREFACE("preface"), APPENDIX("appendix"), PART("part")
  ChapterType(String value) { this.value = value }
  String value
  String getKey() { name() }
  String toString() { value }
}
```

But when I try to list the Chapter objects, I get:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum const class com.wbr.manning.common.ChapterType.part
    at java.lang.Enum.valueOf(Enum.java:196)
    at grails.orm.HibernateCriteriaBuilder.invokeMethod(HibernateCriteriaBuilder.java:1163)
    at com.wbr.manning.agileAuthor.AAChapterController$_closure3.doCall(AAChapterController.groovy:39)
    at com.wbr.manning.agileAuthor.AAChapterController$_closure3.doCall(AAChapterController.groovy)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
2012-04-02 09:55:23,401 [http-8080-1] ERROR common.ErrorsController  - org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.errors.GrailsWrappedRuntimeException: No enum const class com.wbr.manning.common.ChapterType.part
```

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong here?  Do I have the enum correct, or do I need to look at the calling code?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to lookup the Enum based on it's value, you need to add a static method to your enum like so:

```
static ChapterType fromString( type ) {
  ChapterType.values().find { it.value == type }
}
```

You can then do:

```
ChapterType c = ChapterType.fromString( 'part' )
```

Comment: Great to know, thank you!  I solved the problem by changing the values in the database, but this is certainly more elegant!

Comment: In most implementations, the name of this method is `getInstance`

Answer (score 3):

`No enum const class com.wbr.manning.common.ChapterType.part`

Should be `ChapterType.PART`. You *must* respect case-sensitivity.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your calling code. On line 39 of `AAChapterController.groovy` a criteria query is being built that calls

```
ChapterType.valueOf("part")
```

But it should call

```
ChapterType.valueOf("PART")
```

If you can't see the literal string `"part"` here, look for a String variable and call `.toUpperCase()` on it

Comment: Turns out it hinged on what was in the database.  Thank you!